# How do I construct an instance of std::priority_queue from a Container object without an explicit Compare object?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

As per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), std::priority_queue is defined as a template of three arguments, `T`, `Container` and `Compare`, out of which the last two have default values based on `T`:

```
class Container = std::vector<T>,
class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
```

Now let's say that I'm very happy with these defaults, and want to construct an `std::priority_queue<int>` object from an existing `std::vector<int>` one.

The closest I [can](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) have is

```
priority_queue(const Compare& compare, Container&& cont);
```

which move-constructs the underlying container using `cont` and then heapifies it by calling `std::make_heap`.

It's all great, but I would have to explicitly provide a `Compare` object, i.e.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// filling vec with values
std::priority_queue<int> pq{std::less<int>(), std::move(vec)};
```

Why doesn't std::priority_queue have constructors like

```
priority_queue(const Container& cont);
priority_queue(Container&& cont);
```

It only seems reasonable, as it has a comparator-only constructor:

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& compare)
: priority_queue(compare, Container()) { }
```

Or am I missing some other way to do it?

Comment: No. The std::priority_queue violates principles of least astonishment in several ways.  But it is great class and those 16 characters of "std::less<int>()" are not too lot. Most safe and most efficient is most verbose in C++ as rule. Haven't you noticed how omitting "const&" can trash the performance? Thats why.

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement is reasonable and I was considering the use case too, but sadly the STL doesn't support it. Then we can consider making our own wrapper: We just inherit the `priority_queue`, and make a cast:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename Seq = std::vector<T>,
          typename Cmp = std::less<typename Seq::value_type>>
class MyPriorityQueue : public std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp> {
 public:
  using base_t = std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp>;
  MyPriorityQueue() = default;
  template <typename Cont>
  MyPriorityQueue(Cont&& cont) : base_t(Cmp{}, std::move(cont)) {}
  template <typename Cont>
  MyPriorityQueue(const Cont& cont) : base_t(Cmp{}, cont) {}
};

template <typename Cont, typename T = typename Cont::value_type,
          typename Seq = std::vector<T>,
          typename Cmp = std::less<typename Seq::value_type>>
std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp> MakePriorityQueue(Cont&& cont) {
  return std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp>(
      MyPriorityQueue<T, Seq, Cmp>(std::move(cont)));
}

template <typename Cont, typename T = typename Cont::value_type,
          typename Seq = std::vector<T>,
          typename Cmp = std::less<typename Seq::value_type>>
std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp> MakePriorityQueue(const Cont& cont) {
  return std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp>(MyPriorityQueue<T, Seq, Cmp>(cont));
}
template <typename T, typename Seq = std::vector<T>,
          typename Cmp = std::less<typename Seq::value_type>>
std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp> MakePriorityQueue() {
  return std::priority_queue<T, Seq, Cmp>(MyPriorityQueue<T, Seq, Cmp>());
}
```

The usage would be clean:

```cpp
  std::vector<int> vec;
  auto pq = MakePriorityQueue(std::move(vec));
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hM13EPq4o)